# Incomplete type is not allowed error and a tuple

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std

So I am facing this error

> Incomplete type is not allowed

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, bool, float> human = {345, true, 2.33}; 
    // Incomplete type is not allowed  

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: `#include <tuple>` ?

Comment: You've included every header except the one you need. :)

Comment: Un-related: change `system("pause");` to `std::cin.get();` to make the code portable.

Comment: C++ error reporting at the best.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to `#include <tuple>` to be able to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The header file  has not been included.